# Post my website to facebook wall

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I would like to embed a facebook button on my website so that users can post the page to their facebook wall.

[image]

Something like this.i cant find a good tutorial for this.How to embed this and make it possible by using javascript?I have already made the facebook app and got my app ID.Dont know what to do next.Any help?

Comment: Take a look on Facebook's developer site: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/share-button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did this for the first time today.

The next step will be adding the open graph values as meta tags in the head element page. As, someone else pointed out, this information can be found on the developers Facebook reference page. Make sure you put the "Facebook script" after the body tag or you will get a whole bunch of errors and it will not work.

Once your finished, you can use Facebook's debug tool to test if it's working properly (also available in developer section).

Again, you will need to make sure you put the "Facebook script" after your body tag or this will not have any effect on how your page posts.

```
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=258515144314430";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

Then put this in your `head` element.

```
<head>
    <title>Hello World!</title>
    <meta property="fb:app_id" content="000000000000">
    <meta property="og:title" content="Hello World">
    <meta property="og:site_name" content="The Wonderful World of Hellos">
    <meta property="og:url" content="http://blahblahblah.com">
    <meta property="og:description" content="Check out how to say hello to the world!">
    <meta property="og:image" content="http://link-to-image.jpg">
</head>
```

Comment: Meta tag? Can you help me how to do that? I have got the like button,and when i click on it,it opens the dialogue box for posting,but the href is not coming well.